# How can I revert files and folders after I mistakenly add files from Flutter commands in Android Studio?

Tags: flutter, git, android-studio

I did the command

```
flutter create --platforms=windows,macos,linux .
```

mistakenly under the "ios" directory.
I just wanted to add platforms to an existing flutter project.

The command above adds many config files under the wrong directory so I want them restored.

[image]

I did git reset -hard but the files are still there.
How can I revert them?

Comment: do you have manual configuration on iso folder ?

Comment: I have no idea about manual config in ios folder. I sometimes edit files there but this folder is originally there as one of the constitution of Flutter project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, you are using git and it yiu haven’t committed the changes yet, try-

> git chekout .

But before doing that take a copy of your file must. Hope this will help